# Set python workspace environment to Debian VM when on OSX in VS Code

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I am experimenting with setting up Visual Studio Code as my Django IDE, however I'm having difficulty configuring my python workspace environment correctly, such that I can get intellisense for 3rd party modules (like Django) working.

My desktop is Mac OSX, but I run my actual Django environment in a Debian instance inside of virtual box, running on my Mac. I also run Debian in production. I use an NFS share my django project files and virtualenv files between Debian and OSX.

I tried following [these instructions](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Miscellaneous#select-an-interpreter) for configuring my interpreter, however if I set a custom path like:

`/Users/myusername/.virtualenv/myenv/bin/python2.7`

It won't work, because that's a debian binaries, not Mac OSX.

In PyCharm I believe there is a way to specify remote interpreters, even on different architectures. There's no way to do something like this in VS Code, right?

Comment: What I usually do to workaround situations like this is keep another venv on my host machine that has all the same packages. It's not ideal by any means but it works.

Comment: Thanks!

Agreed this would totally work, just a sort of annoying to have to create a manual mirror of the virtualenv that is in my repo. I can't just check out the virtualenv locally as there are binary files in there. So that means hand maintaining it. I think having to muck with this would make the threshold resistance of switching to VS Code too high for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure what I want is currently impossible. The good news is it's being worked on.

[link to issue #123 RFE: Support Remote Interpreter in pythonVSCode repo](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/123)